# mmenu: expand only one submenu at a time (slidingSubmenus: false)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mmenu

I like to use mmenu: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/ in my Web project. I should set `slidingSubmenus: false` but to save vertical space, I should automatically collapse the previous expanded submenu, if a new submenu is expanded - i.e. only one submenu shall be expanded at the time.
These are requirements of the customer.

Please have a look at this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/O2CCBYuXtxnHH7wbdqMa?p=preview [1]

If we expand *About us*, then *About us 2*, the first one should be collapsed.

Is this possible using native settings or with a simple trick?
I also found [How to toggle the vertical jQuery.mmenu submenus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32257569/how-to-toggle-the-vertical-jquery-mmenu-submenus), but I hope for a cleaner solution
 - badera

[1]
Thanks to *ankoehn* (https://stackoverflow.com/users/5174279/ankoehn) for his answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31727879/4106030 (it is the base of my plunker - I need also a solution for AngularJS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, you could add some jQuery to do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 $('.mm-next').click(function(){
   var myMenu = $(this).closest('.mm-vertical');
   $('.mm-vertical').not(myMenu).removeClass('mm-opened');
  })
})
```

Updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/3kr45X8fPnGMo64wXc7j?p=preview

This simply removes the opened class from items other than the current one you have opened.

Comment: Thank you, Leo! This is great. I see that I need to study some basics about jQuery... - There is an issue, if we have sub-sub menus - we can no more open the 3rd level - however, I think with a little bit more jQuery knowledge, I will be able to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

This amendment allows only a single submenu open at a time, at any level.

```
$('.mm-next').click(function(){
  var myMenu = $(this).closest('.mm-vertical');
  myMenu.parent().children('.mm-vertical').not(myMenu).removeClass('mm-opened');
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/axlVAHBb38boNMoqxJ1D?p=preview
(My first plnkr and SO answer, hope it works :)

Comment: Thanks Dom. If you add also an updated plunker (or jsfiddle or what ever), I will set your answer as accepted.